# imagebutton and new xml. file

Tags: android, imagebutton

I want my imagebutton to open (not an activity) but something like a new xml layout or something of the sort.  I want the users to be able to press the button and when they  do so, it then opens and the users can see text and pictures of information about what thay clicked.  I would like ten image buttons on one single activity. Or is there an alternative method to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a customized dialog here there's an example. http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Imagine this is your main layout, which contains a button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="Press me!"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

And your activity is something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Dialog dialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customizeddialog);
    dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Each time a user clicks the button "Press me!" the activity will display a dialog, this dialog contains the information you need, in this case an image and a text the customized dialog looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This icon means.." >
</TextView>
```

So you are showing a new layout, each time a user clicks your button/imagebutton in the same activity.

Comment: dont understand that pagesorry

Comment: A dialog is a window that is created in the same activity, it is a new window where you can show what you want.

Comment: for me to open a dialog do i need to cerate a new superclass as dialgo

Comment: I don't know how you have implemented your class, but normally you don't need a superclass to create a dialog.